# Is there any way to add Angular components to other websites?

Tags: angular

In the case of React, only some components can be added to the website like the link below.

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Is Angular unable to do this? Where is the guide document if possible?

Comment: Are you looking for https://angular.io/guide/elements?

Comment: Angular needs to be compiled.

Comment: I think I'll know if I test what you said. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike **React**, **Angular** is a standalone framework that's packed and built to be used as a complete standalone front end solution.

This wasn't the case in AngularJS that could be added to another website.

Comment: You mean there is no other way than to add files as a result of compilation like an angular-element?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, you can for example embed a compiled angular application to a website by using an iframe or by adding it to a sub directory etc, in the end it's html and javascript. But you cannot embed it as an angular element that you can customize or send/receive data from if that's what you need.